# Hosts names get clear on network/pc restart

Tags: centos, nginx, centos6

I have nginx set up in my cent os and setting up virtual domians apart from localhost:

```
      test.pluspro.com test2.pluspro.com.
```

after adding the domains to the /etc/hosts file in the system they  are working well.but once the network or pc restart the hosts names get cleared and set to its defaults.

Some one has an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that has nothing to do what how the hostname is set.. edit the following file

```
/etc/sysconfig/network
```

if you don't see a HOSTNAME=some.host.com add it